# Express & JS: Array returned empty, populated late

Tags: javascript, arrays, express, response

I have a route method to return a list of filenames in a http response.

The data structure I am using for the response is eventually populated, albeit after the response is returned, meaning I get an empty and useless response.

I can see the datastructure is populated in the end, as the output the contents to the log show.

Code:

```
app.get('/hello',function(req,res){

    var paths = {};

    fs.readdir('./uploads', function(err, items) {
    console.log(items);

    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        paths[i] = items[i];
        console.log(items[i]);
    }
    });

    res.json(this,paths);
});
```

Comment: Do you mean that the issue is that `res.json(this.paths)` returns an empty JSON response?

Answer (score 2):

You should return response after reading the file directory inside the callback.

Below is the code snippet for the same:

```
app.get('/hello',function(req,res){
    var paths = {};
    fs.readdir('./uploads', function(err, items) {
       console.log(items);
       for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
          paths[i] = items[i];
          console.log(items[i]);
       }
       res.json(paths);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the `res.json()` call inside the callback, after the `for` loop.

EDIT1:

```
app.get('/hello', function (req, res) {

    var paths = [];

    fs.readdir('./uploads', function (err, items) {

        console.log(items);

        for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
            paths.push(items[i]);
            console.log(items[i]);
        }

        res.json(paths);
    });
});
```

Comment: Also, if the `paths` object is going to have numeric keys, then might as well make it an array. In which case, you don't have to use the `for` loop to populate the array, unless you have other operations to perform on each item.